# Assuming a vector field is differentiable is the equality of the mixed partial derivatives a sufficient and necessary for it being conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This takes a little explanation. I know can look this up at wiki but please read my explanation if you allow me. The function I am thinking of is the vector field F = <-y,x> / x^2 + y^2.

Yes, I realize this does not qualify because the function can not be defined at 0 but if you ignore this just for a moment so I can explain my concern.

The function is going around in a curl which means it could never be conservative. Now my question becomes are the mixed partials equal in this case?  It seems to me that the essence of conservative is that the vector field is not twisting , which is nothing more than saying the second mixed partials are equal, i.e. there is no twist, and not the fact that it is not defined at 0.

But there is a twist with this function and shouldn't the second mixed partials be NOT equal to each other? I am not sure I know how because of the x^2 + y^2 in the denominator.  I am stumped.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure where your confusion lies, but here is a blurb explaining what's going on here.

The point is that the vector field 
$$
F(x,y)=\frac{(-y,x)}{x^2+y^2}
$$
is irrotational, which a quick calculation of the curl will show. What is going on here is that the domain of the vector field is not without "holes," or put more fancily, is simply connected.

Why do we care?

The issue is that the way in which we construct potentials for vector fields is by integrating along a path to find the antiderivative, if the integral is path dependent, then this integral will not be well defined as a function. On a region that isn't simply connected, there will be no guarantee that integrating will be independent of path.

Try integrating your function a path from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$ along the boundary of the unit circle. You will find a value of $\pi$. Do this in the other direction, you will find a value of $-\pi$. So how should we define our potential function there?